# Error occurs when debugging Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms solution and I am working on app on Android phone. Everything was working good, but than problem appeared. When I Start Without Debugging this project, app works as expected. When I Start Debugging, debugger is stepping through lines slower than it used to. And then it steps to line InitializeComponent(); in constructor of LoginPage() (first page in app) and is stepping through this step infinitely. It can't reach next line, since it is busy evaluating this line.

I don't have any change in code compared to my pears. Same is happening on phone and simulator. I have last version of Xamarin Forms 4.3.0.795 and Visual Studio 2015.

I noticed in Output one line that appears while evaluating InitializeComponent():

AOT module 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.Acumenics.Genea-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.so" not found

I don't know what could cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working again. I installed a bit older version of Xamarin (4.3.0.784), restarted computer, cleaned solution and deleted shared mono runtime from phone. I also first time started without debugging.

Edit: I experienced same problem again and above solution didn't work. I checked out one month old code and after that debugging worked again. When debugging starts working once it works with newest code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38378

More specifically, take a look at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38378#c11

If that doesn't help, you could...

1. Try disabling Mono Shared Runtime?

   - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38378#c12

and/or

2. Try deleting the existing shared mono runtime from his device(s)

   - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38378#c13

Comment: I understood that only suggested solution is to uninstall shared mono runtime. I tried that without success.